# How to upgrade asdf version in quicklisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf

I want to compile and run a lisp source code to parse peercoin blockchain so that i can get top 100 richest addresses. I am using lisp source code https://github.com/glv2/peercoin-blockchain-parser. 
I have installed quicklisp on my system, but while running the code below error being thrown :

```
debugger invoked on a LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002A8AF63}>: 
Error while trying to load definition for system bordeaux-threads from
pathname /home/deepchand/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/bordeaux-threads-v0.8.5/bordeaux-threads.asd: 
READ error during COMPILE-FILE: 
You need ASDF >= 3.1 to load this system correctly.
(in form starting at line: 1, column: 0, file-position: 0)
```

How do i update asdf to resolve this error ?

Comment: Please provide the result of `(lisp-implementation-type)` and `(lisp-implementation-version)` when you have such errors.

Comment: @coredump
Result : 
(lisp-implementation-type)

"SBCL"
0] (lisp-implementation-version)

"1.1.14.debian"
0]

Comment: I would suggest just to get a newer version of SBCL (1.3.20). But I would still want the answer to this question though :)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

1. Download the version of asdf.lisp you want from https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html.  In my case, I copied mine from my system's installed copy located at /usr/share/common-lisp/source
2. Put the new copy in the ~/quicklisp directory, or whichever directory your quicklisp is located, overwriting the old asdf.lisp in that directory.
3. Delete the ~/quicklisp/cache directory.
4. Restart your lisp.  It will take a while to repopulate the ~/quicklisp/cache directory so be patient.

Answer (score 0):

For other lisp implementations, say LispWorks, you can solve this problem by downloading asdf.lisp 3.1 or later from the asdf website and then  putting

```
(load "asdf.lisp")
```

in your initialization file prior to loading quicklisp. LispWorks[1] recommends you also do

```
(provide "asdf")
```

Worked for me.

[1] http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/LW/html/lw-312.htm

Answer (score 0):

See https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Upgrading-ASDF

You can

> download an official tarball or checkout a release from git into ~/common-lisp/asdf/.

Then it should be found on start-up. I think that's all (I did it recently and don't remember other steps).